# changing loaded page component based on clicked link in sidebar

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm making my first PWA in react and while I've worked in react before I'm trying to do things a bit more cleanly and modularly.

Currently I have a main page which has a sidebar with links, then a main page which shows the title (link name) at the top and then some cards within a content component.

This is all good so far, and if I click the dashboard link in the sidebar then the title state changes on the main page to show Dashboard. Same goes for the trends link. However, my issue is that when I click on these I also want to change the page content as well as the title at the top.

Currently my `App.js` just shows the `ContentComponent.js` component in the body. How can I implement a change so that if I click "Dashboard" it loads `ContentCOmponent.js` but if I click "Trends" Then I could load something else like `TrendsCOmponent.js`?

App.js

```
class App extends React.Component {

    state = { selectedItem: 'Dashboard' };

    componentDidMount() {
        window.addEventListener('resize', this.resize);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        window.removeEventListener('resize', this.resize);
    }

    resize = () => this.forceUpdate();

    render() {
        const { selectedItem } = this.state;
        return (
            <Row className={css(styles.container)}>
                <SidebarComponent selectedItem={selectedItem} onChange={(selectedItem) => this.setState({ selectedItem })} />
                <Column flexGrow={1} className={css(styles.mainBlock)}>
                    <HeaderComponent title={selectedItem} />
                    <div className={css(styles.content)}>
                        <ContentComponent />
                    </div>
                </Column>
            </Row>
        );
    }
}
export default App;
```

SidebarComponent.js

```
class SidebarComponent extends React.Component {

    state = { expanded: false };

    onItemClicked = (item) => {
        this.setState({ expanded: false });
        return this.props.onChange(item);
    }

    isMobile = () => window.innerWidth <= 768;

    toggleMenu = () => this.setState(prevState => ({ expanded: !prevState.expanded }));

    renderBurger = () => {
        return <div onClick={this.toggleMenu} className={css(styles.burgerIcon)}>
            <IconBurger />
        </div>
    }

    render() {
        const { expanded } = this.state;
        const isMobile = this.isMobile();
        return (
            <div style={{ position: 'relative' }}>
                <Row className={css(styles.mainContainer)} breakpoints={{ 768: css(styles.mainContainerMobile, expanded && styles.mainContainerExpanded) }}>
                    {(isMobile && !expanded) && this.renderBurger()}
                    <Column className={css(styles.container)} breakpoints={{ 768: css(styles.containerMobile, expanded ? styles.show : styles.hide) }}>
                        <LogoComponent />
                        <Column className={css(styles.menuItemList)}>
                            <MenuItemComponent
                                title="Dashboard" 
                                onClick={() => this.onItemClicked('Dashboard')}
                                active={this.props.selectedItem === 'Dashboard'}
                            />
                            <MenuItemComponent
                                title="Trends" 
                                onClick={() => this.onItemClicked('Trends')}
                                active={this.props.selectedItem === 'Trends'}
                            />
                        </Column>
                    </Column>
                    {isMobile && expanded && <div className={css(styles.outsideLayer)} onClick={this.toggleMenu}></div>}
                </Row>
            </div>
        );
    };
}

export default SidebarComponent;
```

ContentComponent.js

```
function ContentComponent() {
return (
    <Column>
        <Row className={css(styles.cardsContainer)} wrap flexGrow={1} horizontal="space-between" breakpoints={{ 768: 'column' }}>
            <Row className={css(styles.cardRow)} wrap flexGrow={1} horizontal="space-between" breakpoints={{ 384: 'column' }}>
                <MiniCardComponent className={css(styles.miniCardContainer)} title="Dashboard" value="60" />
                <MiniCardComponent className={css(styles.miniCardContainer)} title="Trends" value="16" />
            </Row>
            <Row className={css(styles.cardRow)} wrap flexGrow={1} horizontal="space-between" breakpoints={{ 384: 'column' }}>
                <MiniCardComponent className={css(styles.miniCardContainer)} title="Total View" value="43" />
                <MiniCardComponent className={css(styles.miniCardContainer)} title="Achievements" value="64" />
            </Row>
        </Row>
        <div className={css(styles.todayTrends)}>
            <TodayTrendsComponent />
        </div>
        <Row horizontal="space-between" className={css(styles.lastRow)} breakpoints={{ 1024: 'column' }}>
            <UnresolvedTicketsComponent containerStyles={styles.unresolvedTickets} />
            <TasksComponent containerStyles={styles.tasks} />
        </Row>
    </Column>
   );
}

export default ContentComponent;
```

Comment: Try using `react-router`. It simplifies things for you.

Comment: Thank you, I'll look at that now. Will that allow me to keep this structure but only load certain content components into app.js depending on the click?

Comment: Yes.. not exactly click, but Link works the same way as <a> but for soft refresh.